# Htaccess rewrite if file not found

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Guys i am running a WordPress multisite in which i wanted to load a file from a diff location if the file is not found in the requested location

Eg :

Requested URL : `http://example.com/wp-content/sites/2/uploads/2018/01/filename.jpg`

if the file exists it can load from that url if not the path should be rewirted

Rewrite url  `http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/filename.jpg`

This should be done once for the url which has **sites/{anynumber}/uploads**/

i tried with the below htaccess code

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/uploads/sites/\d{4}/\d{2}/.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(uploads/sites)(/\d{4}/\d{2}/.+)$ $1/uploads$2
```

but i get  500 error

And here is my full htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp400/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/uploads/sites/\d{4}/\d{2}/.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(uploads/sites)(/\d{4}/\d{2}/.+)$ $1/uploads$2
```